# PHP breadcrumbs loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm stuck with a small PHP loop.

My query returns 10 rows, with columns 'id' and 'parentId'. I'm trying to create an array of parent ids to use for breadcrumbs on a site.

Current page ID is '6'. It's parent is '5', which again has page '3' as parent. Page '3' has '0' as parent... Array should then be 5, 3, 0.

```
$stmt = $db->query("
    SELECT id, parentId
    FROM cat
");
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

function crumbs($rows, $id = '6') {
    $crumbs = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['id'] == $id) {
            if ($row['parentId'] != 0) {
                crumbs($rows, $row['parentId']);
            }
            $crumbs[] = $row['parentId'];
        }
    }
    // echo $crumbs returns Array, Array, Array...
    return $crumbs;
}

$json['crumbs'][] = crumbs($rows);
// ...but $json['crumbs'] return only one Array (5).

echo json_encode($json);
```

Edit: MySql Rows:

```
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   3
5   3
6   5
7   7
9   2
12  3
```

And a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89845a)

Comment: The better solution would actually be to get MySQL to return exactly what you want.

Comment: Can you please provide 10 rows of data, and desired results. This looks like it could be a very simple MySQL query without the whole loop.

Comment: Also, do you have a maximum depth in mind?

Comment: Create a sqlfiddle and perhaps @Pachonk is up for doing a self-join. Right now you could support your question better with a fiddle. Otherwise apathy can set in for the answer people

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ you can use text-to-ddl to really speed up creation time.

Comment: Hi. I added the rows to brief.

The number of rows and depth varies from time to time, but should always end when the next parentId is 0.

Comment: Is there ever a max depth, like for instance maxdepth of 5?

Comment: No, it should be limitless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that will use pure MySQL to get you all parent child relationships off of 1 parent:

**Query**:

```
SELECT  @r AS _id,
         (
         SELECT  @r := parent
         FROM    nav
         WHERE   id = _id
         ) AS parent,
         @l := @l + 1 AS level
 FROM    (
         SELECT  @r := 6,
                 @l := 0
         ) vars,
         nav h
WHERE    @r <> 0
```

**Results**:

```
| _id | parent | level |
|-----|--------|-------|
|   6 |      5 |     1 |
|   5 |      3 |     2 |
|   3 |      0 |     3 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89845a/8

Comment: Amazing. Screw php :) Thank you!

Comment: For the record, most of that type of messing around can be saved on the mysql side, but there is a line that must be drawn when it comes to time and effort.

Comment: The one thing you want to be careful with is using too many variables and using loops. When queries get complex, make them stored procs (they're like functions that php can call and pass in args)